# $A^T$ has the same Smith normal form as $A$

Tags: matrices, smith-normal-form

Let $A\in R^{n\times m}$ be a matrix over a PID $R$. Show that $A$ and its transpose $A^T$ have the same [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form), meaning that the ideals $\{0_R\}\subsetneq \langle d_r \rangle \subseteq \dots \subseteq \langle d_2 \rangle \subseteq \langle d_1 \rangle$ and $r$ are the same for both matrices.

---

My attempt is pretty fast and "too easy" that's why I want to check if it's correct and I didn't miss anything.

Let $A \in R^{n\times m}$ and $S,T$ matrices such that $SAT=\text{diag}(d_1,...,d_r)$. Then:
\begin{align*}
\Rightarrow \quad A = S^{-1}\text{diag}(d_1,...,d_r)T^{-1}
\end{align*}
in which $S^{-1}, T^{-1}$ exist since they are invertible by definition.
\begin{align*}
\Rightarrow \quad A^T &= (S^{-1}\text{diag}(d_1,...,d_r)T^{-1})^T = (T^{-1})^T (\text{diag}(d_1,...,d_r))^T(S^{-1})^T \\
&=(T^{-1})^T \text{diag}(d_1,...,d_r)(S^{-1})^T 
\end{align*}
because the transpose of a matrix with entries only on its main diagonal stays the same. So $A^T$ seems to have the same invariants $d_1,...,d_r$ as $A$.

Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: If in the last line you write $(S^T)^{-1}$ instead of $(S^{-1})^T$, and similarly for $T$ (what a bad choice to use $T$ for a matrix and to denote the transpose!), then the things are even more clear.

Comment: You should include in the notation to say there are $0$'s for the remaining diagonal entries and how many. Otherwise $\text{diag}(d_1 \cdots d_r)$ is either denoting an r by r matrix (which is not what you want) or there are some number of $0$'s but ambiguously you haven't said how many.

Comment: @user26857 Isn't $(S^T)^{-1} = (S^{-1})^T$?

Comment: @AHusain Correct, thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is, but it looks better un order to conclude something about SNF.